# Problems with Chromium sandbox

Tags: chromium

Since yesterday, a couple of web apps I regularly use (namely Popocorn Time and Whatsapp for Web) have stopped working. Here's the error message I get:

```
 [3101:0807/160625:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(170)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you upgrade anything?

Comment: I'd just come home from a 3-week vacation, so I had quite a few updates indeed.